# Excel: Leer archivo .dbf con Ms Query desde otras fuentes

Tags: excel, vba

Entorno: Ms Office 2010, Windows 10

No he podido obtener la información de esta base de datos con extensión .dbf usando Ms Query (desde otras fuentes), tal vez mi fuente de datos está mal configurada pero ya probé con todos los drivers que manejan este formato, por ejemplo "Driver do Microsoft dBASE (*.dbf)", "Visual Fox Pro tables", etc. también he elegido todas las extensiones existentes (III, IV and 5.0), después me marca el error "imposible el acceso a la tabla ...", no tengo ideo de cómo configurar esta conexión a la base de datos para que se muestre en sql.

Me piden que extraer la información desde esta herramienta de Excel, pero código de Visual Basic también es bienvenido.

Este es un link al archivo "zonas.dbf" https://ufile.io/vuhfk

Muchas gracias de antemano por su apoyo, un cordial saludo.

Comment: Los quieres leer en ese formato siempre o los quieres exportar? yo lo exporté todos los datos de unos DBF directamente a SQL Server

Comment: o este driver te falta MICROSOFT OLE DB PROVIDER FOR VISUAL FOXPRO VERSION 9.0

Comment: Descargue tu archivo, y no es un DBF suelto, esta linkeado a una base de datos DBC propia de VFP, por lo tanto no vas a poder abrirla a memos que antes rompas ese vinculo, yo si logre abrirlo en VFP, rompiendo el vinculo, abriendolo en modo exclusivo.